# How to format output of Export-Excel in order to get colored header in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

The code below is working fine to export data, but I need the header / first row to have custom background and text colors. I would like the header to be filled with yellow with blue text.

```
$csvFile = "C:\temp\filename.csv"

$excelfile = "C;\temp\Excelfile.xlsx"

$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$data | Export-Excel $excelfile -AutoSize -AutoFilter
```

I tried a few parameters for `Export-Excel` but none of them worked and I got the following error:

`parameter Not found`

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: Change the semicolon `;` to a colon `:` in the second line

Comment: Next, have a close look at all possible parameters for [Export-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Export-Excel.ps1), especially `TitleBackgroundColor`

Comment: Hi @Theo. Thank you so much for your comments. Yes colon was already fixed as its just a typo , when i tried to copy here. i tried to put -tileBackgroundcolor in export excel , but i guess i have to make a function or something to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
$csvFile = "C:\temp\filename.csv"

$excelfile = "C:\temp\Excelfile.xlsx"

$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 

$ConditionalFormat =$(
    New-ConditionalText -Range 'A1' -BackgroundColor Yellow -ConditionalTextColor Blue
)
$data | Export-Excel $excelfile -ConditionalFormat $ConditionalFormat -show
```

I added the `-show` at the end to auto open the `$excelfile`, but it is not necessary.

(I realize this post is ancient, just wanted to throw it out there for anyone else)